# Wordpress, FTP, and managing files

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ftp

Im making the jump from using a theme to actually coding the sites on wordpress. I know how to build a site from scratch and use FTP to get files on the server. How do I do this with wordpress? I have a site I want to customize in WP and it is overwhelming. I dont want to create a child theme, want to use other JS libraries and stuff. How do I do this without losing everything from the "page builder"? thanks

Comment: what do you mean by page builder? something that generates HTML for you? Do you know what a skeletal wordpress Theme looks like? You would work from something like www.Roots.io maybe and once you have built a theme, just upload that folder to the wp-content/themes directory using FTP (or some other method)

Comment: Using a specific theme with a plugin to visually construct pages. I also dont understand how WP organizes pages and how I can add custom code to my existing site

Comment: @NICK You seem to be asking for a general guide which is beyond the scope of a single Stack Oveflow Q&A. Try to break your problems into chunks and ask specific questions.

Comment: how to I organize my life? haha Im just kidding. Thanks for the guidance Mr. Jones